# How do I set NetBeans as the default for .java files?

Tags: java, default-programs, netbeans

I want .java files to open with NetBeans, but Ubuntu doesn't offer the option, neither in the drop down menu nor properties>open with.

I also should mention that I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT: Nevermind. I was eventually unable to do it, or to get netbeans to compile, or th use this version or that, so I gave up. I finaly managed to get gedit configured correctly, so this problem is not moot. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @kraxor I'm using 14.04, plain vanilla Ubuntu, as opposed to Xubuntu or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Can I associate a file type with NetBeans to be able to open files of that type from File Explorer?

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCliOpen

Yes, you can. Just pass the name of the file to be opened as the only argument in your command line interface.

For example:
**`netbeans MyFile.java`**

---

**The same command can be used to create an association for files of specific types in the file manager (below)**

You can also use the explicit --open option for clarity, and pass more than one file; for example, on Unix:
**`find src -name \*.java -print0 | xargs -0 netbeans --open`**

If there is an instance of the IDE already running, the file will simply open in this instance and the command will exit. You may need to pass the --userdir option to match the user directory of the running IDE.

In addition, you can specify the line at which the file should open (line numbers start at 1):
**`netbeans Something.java:55`**

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't let me input a path. It offers me options, none of them Netbeans.

Comment: @Mack - answer edited

Comment: @boon - I tried this and it still opens with gedit and doesn't give me the option for netbeans. should I put in the path to netbeans?

Comment: Wait, I may have found the problem. I used the Netbeans installer, and the system doesn't think it has netbeans installed. I'm installing netbeans now with apt-get. I'll report back with the results.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. Still no option.

Comment: @Mack - Found a promising article on their FaQ. Updated answer to reflect research.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct, whether or not it is, because Netbeans refuses to compile or run files, no matter how I link it to which JDK, so I'm giving up on it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually, I finally got netbeans to compile, it just refuses to do it when a file is not in a project. But that issue is for another time. I had seen the faq before, and it didn't help. Still opens with gedit.